# XSLT - Remove nodes when current node is equal to previous node

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to write XSLT for an xml which contains in below format.

```
<books>
<book>
 <a>name</a>
 <a>name</a>
 <b>name</b>
 <b>name</b>
</book>
</books>
```

I need to eliminate the duplicate child nodes in some conditions.

1. Only if(current node == previous node) then it should be removed.

ie.. if previous node (element) is `<a>`  and current node (element) is also `<a>`, Then one node should be removed.

output for the above be,

```
`<a>name</a>`

`<b>name</b>`
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried

Comment: I had an idea , cant able to do in xslt @RaR

Comment: And you will need to explain clearly what determines that "nodes are equal", is that simply based on the element name (e.g. two `a` elements) or based on the content (e.g. `name`) or on both the name and the content? Also explain which XSLT version you use or can use.

Comment: The question is edited above , plz verify @Martin Honnen

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2 or 3? There it is easy to process e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name(.)"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each-group>` to eliminate adjacent duplicates based on the node name.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can easily group adjacent sibling elements by their node name with `for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()"` and simply output the first item in each group (which is equal to the context item `.`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="book">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKw4/1

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to omit a **leaf element** (without children elements)
if it has a previous sibling, which:

- is also a **leaf element**,
- has the **same name**,
- has the **same text content**.

So the most intuitive solution (I think) is to write an empty template,
matching just these nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][preceding-sibling::*[1][not(*)]
  [name() = current()/name()][text() = current()/text()]]"/>
```

A brief description of the match attribute:

- `*[not(*)]` - Every element without any child element (leaf element).
- `[` - Start of the second predicate.

  - `preceding-sibling::*[1]` - Take the first preceding sibling.
  - `[not(*)]` - It must not have any child element.
  - `[name() = current()/name()]` - It must have the same name as the
    "starting" element.
  - `[text() = current()/text()]` - It must have the same text as the
    "starting" element.
- `]` - End of the second predicate.

Of course, the script must contain also an *identity template*.

For a working example, with a bit extended source, see http://xsltransform.net/jxN8Nqm

If requirement concerning the same text is not necessary, delete the respective
predicate fragment.